# How to use basic authentication for WMS layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I use Leaflet.

A governmental agency provides a WMS layer with basic authentication. I first added and published it on my Geoserver and it worked, but I could not access the different styles. They suggested me to connect directly to their URL without going via Geoserver. How do I provide the credentials (username / password) for the authentication in a secure way when connecting directly to their GetCapabilities URL?

```
var wmsLayer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://maps-ver.lantmateriet.se/fastighet/wms/v1.1?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1', {
                layers: 'granser',
                styles: 'morkbakgrund',
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true
            }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: The only way is using SSL (https).

Comment: @TomazicM What is the next best alternative I have, since they don't use https? I don't even know how to pass the credentials. Can't find "Authentication" or anything similar as an option in leaflet wms.

Comment: I don't think there is an alternative, you are out of luck here.

Comment: @TomazicM It doesn't help that my page is https? And lets say the URL was https, how would I anyway set the credentials? I can't find it in Leaflet documentation regarding WMS.

Comment: No, it doesn't help that your page is https. Authentication has nothing to do with WMS, it's tied to web server and is dependent of server implementation of authentication. That's not GIS question, so you better try on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TomazicM OK, thank you very much for taking your time!